# Magento2.1.9 - Error on shipment generation save

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipment, carrier

I'm debuging code got error in exception error :

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'There is no active transaction' in /public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:316
Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(316): PDO->commit() 
#1 /public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(510): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_commit() 
#2 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(253): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->commit() 
#3 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/AbstractResource.php(74): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->commit() 
#4 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Transaction.php(57): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource->commit() 
#5 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Transaction.php(147): Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction->_commitTransaction() 
#6 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save.php(79): Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction->save() 
#7 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save.php(153): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save->_saveShipment(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment)) 
#8 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save->execute() 
#9 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#10 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#11 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array) 
#12 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Shippin...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...') 
#13 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#14 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#15 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Shippin...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...') 
#16 /public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#17 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#18 /public_html/var/generation/Magento/Shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array) 
#19 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#20 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#21 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array) 
#22 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install') 
#23 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#24 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#25 /public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array) 
#26 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#27 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() 
#28 /public_html/index.php(42): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http)) 
#29 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you programatically trying to ship orders?  I saw this error when I was developing an extension.  But it was simply down to how I approached generating the shipment.  I made a mistake with the method I chose to use.

https://github.com/DominicWatts/AutoShipment/blob/master/Helper/Shipment.php#L153-L188

This should work

```
    public function markAsShipped($order, $doNotify = true)
    {
        if (!$order || !$order->canShip()) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            $orderShipment = $this->convertOrder->toShipment($order);
            foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
                if (!$orderItem->getQtyToShip() || $orderItem->getIsVirtual()) {
                    continue;
                }
                $shipmentItem = $this->convertOrder
                    ->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem)
                    ->setQty($orderItem->getQtyToShip());
                $orderShipment->addItem($shipmentItem);
            }
            $orderShipment->register();
            $orderShipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);

            $orderShipment->save();
            $orderShipment->getOrder()->save();

            if ($doNotify) {
                $this->objectManager->create(\Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier::class)
                    ->notify($orderShipment);
                $orderShipment->save();
            }

            $order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), 'Order has been marked as complete');
            $order->save();

            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
        }
        return false;
    }
```